# Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: angular

soy nuevo en este mundo de la programacion (aun estoy estudiando) tengo 2 problemas... el primero es que al querer hacer la interpolacion del servicio en el HTML me manda este error "Typeerror: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"... buscando vi una solucion usando *ngIf pero me me dice que la propiedad no existe y ya no se que poner...

```js
//*esto seria en el template*//

 <h1 class="display-1">{{miPorfolio.name}}</h1>
```

```css
//*y esta la carga del servicio en el componente*//

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PorfolioService } from 'src/app/servicies/porfolio.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
miPorfolio:any;

  constructor(private datosPorfolio:PorfolioService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datosPorfolio.obtenerDatos().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.miPorfolio = data;
    });
  }

}

) export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  miPorfolio: any;
  constructor(private datosPorfolio: PorfolioService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datosPorfolio.obtenerDatos().subscribe(data=> {
      console.log(data);
      this.miPorfolio=data;
    }
    );
  }
}
```

```html
//*esta es la carga del servicio*// 

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PorfolioService {

  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  obtenerDatos():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('./assets/data/data.json');
  }
}
```

y el segundo problema... al cargar el servicio nos dieron el ejemplo de carga en solo una componente, yo tengo 7, si hago la carga en cada uno me da error, deberia hacer una carga global? como seria? muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes revisar las rutas importadas de tu servicio, trata que el editor de código o si tienes VSCode lo autocomplete.

También, lo que puedes hacer es validar si hay datos en tu subscripción por ejemplo:

```
this.datosPorfolio.obtenerDatos().subscribe((data : any) => {
                  if(data){
                     this.miPorfolio = data;
                  }
});
```

Otra cosa importante que debes ver es si tus datos en data.json es un arreglo o es solo un objeto, en caso que quieras acceder a un objeto necesitas acceder a su posición dentro del arreglo.

En caso de que sí sea un arreglo cambia any por any[], tanto en el servicio como en tu variable del componente es decir:

```
miPorfolio: any;
```

Por:

```
miPorfolio:any[] = [];
```

En tu servicio:

```
 obtenerDatos():Observable<any>{
            return this.http.get('./assets/data/data.json');
 }
```

Por:

```
 obtenerDatos():Observable<any[]>{
            return this.http.get('./assets/data/data.json');
}
```

Y para evitar el error de undefined puedes usar algo como, '?' para evitar que Angular lea la propiedad en undefined:

```
    <h1 class="display-1">{{miPorfolio?.name || 'En caso de undefined'}}</h1>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio mucho tu solucion! efectivamente mi data.json es un objeto asi que aplique lo que me indicaste y el error desaparecio. te pregunto, es necesario hacer el mismo procedimiento en cada componente de mi angular o solo con implementarlo el por ejemple el componente header ya puedo disponer de los datos en todos los componentes? o deberia crear una funcion distinta?, perdon por estas preguntas basicas, el contenido y los profesores del curso no nos explican casi nada!

Comment: El tema de comunicación entre componentes es muy vasto, puedes hacerlo de muchas maneras, la más facil es llamar a un servicio y servir esa información en cada componente en el constructor en el caso que no tenga nada que ver un componente con el otro. Ahora si los componentes sí tienen que ver es decir tienes componentes anidados, lo recomendado es utilizar el componente padre como principal fuente de datos y pasar a través del decorador @Input los datos a los hijos, y evitar usar servicios en los componentes hijos, es decir si tienes un método de guardar hazlo en el padre y no en los hijos.